# How to use React router v6.4 with typescript properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use react-router-dom v6.4+ in my project. I implemented it as a route array of objects. Its worked as routing but suddenly I got another issue realated this. I can't call any hook inside the Component which located on `element` property in route array.
In the `route.ts` file:

```
import MainLayout from './container/layouts/mainLayout/MainLayout'
import ErrorPage from './view/Error'
import Home from './view/Home'

const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: MainLayout(),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: Home(),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    element: ChangeRoute('/404'),
  },
  {
    path: '/404',
    element: ErrorPage(),
  },
]

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes)

export default router
```

and in the `app.ts` file:

```
<RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={<React.Fragment>Loading ...</React.Fragment>} />
```

But If I try to use any hook , inside **MainLayout** component , its saying
[image: this error in console]

code in `MainLayout` component :

```
const MainLayout = () => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Layout className='layout'>
      <SideBar collapsed={collapsed} />
      <Layout>
        <Topbar collapsed={collapsed} setCollapsed={setCollapsed} />
        <Outlet />
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MainLayout
```

I think if I use `element: <MainLayout/>` instead of `element: MainLayout()`, then this issue will resolve. but typescript doesnt allow me to do this. and on the documentation every thing is on plain javascript. only one type defination there [is this](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#type-declaration)

How to solve this? Kindly guide me.

**Edit**
Here is the codesandbox demo : [visit sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-gates-fw1fhv?file=/src/routes.ts)

Comment: The react docs state that hooks can only be called in components , but you are using the component as a function which is wrong, you have to pass in your component as an element

Comment: Thats what I'm looking for, How to do that? in js ,I can do this, but here ts doesnt allowing me.

Comment: what is the error that typescript is giving you

Comment: ```type MainLayout = /*unresolved*/ any
'MainLayout' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MainLayout'?ts(2749)```

Comment: Hmm, *other than* the incorrect routes config, this seems more like an issue specifically in the `MainLayout` file. Can you edit the post to include a complete [mcve] for us to inspect, along with the complete error message or linting error text and the line of code causing the issue?

Comment: wait , I'm creating a codesandbox demo for you

Comment: you can check now , I added a codesandbox demo

Comment: The code appears to run without issue here in this [forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-react-router-v6-4-with-typescript-properly-h7hti7).

Answer (score 9):

Changes the name of the `route.ts` file to `route.tsx`, now you can will set components in the `element` object property, this works for me.

Comment: lol... I wasted so much time on this silly issue. 'U rock!

Answer (score 0):

The `element` prop expects a `React.ReactNode`, you are directly calling a React function instead of passing it as JSX.

Example:

```
const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    element: <ChangeRoute redirect='/404' />,
  },
  {
    path: '/404',
    element: <ErrorPage />,
  },
]
```

Comment: its giving error man, I pasted the error msg on the comment thread, you can check